# Registry: find and replace part of a path in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, replace, registry

I need to find and replace a specific part of a value in any key below `HKEY_current_user`.
To be precise: it is an `UNC-Path` to a new system in the Network, so I want to search every key below HKCU for the value `\\systema\random\path` and replace it with 
`\\systemb\random\path`. The tricky bit is, that `random\path` is random ;), so I just want to replace `\\systema\` with `\\systemb` and let the rest of the path on its place.

any ideas how to create this for each loop in a Batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED Previous version was not even close to correctly work, thanks Matt.

This should handle values with spaces or underscores in name, the difference in separator between XP and later systems and the fact that XP's reg.exe lacks the /f switch to search for string in registry. But, maybe, not the most elegant solution.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"
    set "search=\\systemA"
    set "replace=\\systemB"

    set "line="
    set "key="
    set "oldKey=@@"
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
        'reg query "HKCU" /s 2^>nul^|findstr /i /l /c:"HKEY_CURRENT" /c:"%search%" 2^> nul'
    ) do (
        for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%b in ("%%~a") do if /i "%%b"=="HKEY" (
            set "key=%%~a"
        ) else (
            if not "!key!"=="!oldKey!" (
                if exist "%tempFile%" del /f /q "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
                reg export "!key!" "%tempFile%"  >nul 
                set "oldKey=!key!"
            )
            for /f "delims=" %%c in (
                'find /i """=" ^< "%tempFile%"'
            ) do (
                set "value="
                for %%d in (%%c) do if not defined value (
                    set "value=1"
                    for /f "tokens=*" %%e in (
                        'reg query "!key!" /v "%%~d" ^| find /i "%%~d" ^| find "%search%"' 
                    ) do (
                        set "data= %%~e"
                        for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ("%%~d") do set "data=!data:*%%~f=!"
                        for /f "tokens=1,*" %%f in ("!data!") do set "data=%%~g"
                        set "data=!data:%search%=%replace%!"
                        echo reg add "!key!" /v "%%~d" /d "!data!" /f
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    del /f /q "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul

exit /b
```

Comment: Exporting to a file was a good idea but it breaks if the data type is REG_EXPAND_SZ or REG_MULTI_SZ since they're output as HEX. Also, when exporting to a file, the \'s are doubled. I think they need to be reduced back to singles for reg.exe input.

Comment: @MattWilliamson, blind, i was blind. Thank you. Code updated to handle the indicated problems and some more i found trying to debug/correct the previous code in a XP machine.

Comment: This worked pretty nice on the testrun. :) thx @MC ND // will also test Matts script on my system. you guys are AWESOME!

Comment: This script is full of bugs like unhandled default values, wrong double quote handling like in /d and keys inside exported reg subkeys. I do not recommend to use it at all...

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set q=reg query "HKCU" /s /d /f "\\systema"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('%q%^|find /i "HKEY_CURRENT"') do (
  for /f "tokens=1,3*" %%b in (
    'reg query "%%a" /s^|find /i "\\systema"'
    ) do (
    set "new=%%c%%d" & set "new=!new:systema=systemb!"
    echo reg add "%%a" /v %%b /d "!new!" /f
  )
)
```

remove the echo on the reg add line once you see acceptable output.

**Revision to work with spaces and underscores in Name value**

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "sysa=\\someoldserv"
set "sysb=\\somenewserver"
set q=reg query "HKCU" /s /d /f "%sysa%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('%q%^|find /i "HKEY_CURRENT"') do (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('reg query "%%a" /s^|find /i "%sysa%"') do (
    call :GetNameWithSpaces "%%b" "%sysa%" name data
    call :trim tname !name!
    call :trim tdata !data!
    set "new=!tdata!" & set "new=!new:%sysa%=%sysb%!"
    echo reg add "%%a" /v "!tname!" /d "!new!" /f
  )
)
exit /b

:GetNameWithSpaces <key> <search> <ReturnName> <ReturnData>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=_" %%b in ("%~1") do (
    set "name=%%b" & set "data=%%c %%d" 
    for /f "tokens=*" %%e in ('echo !name!^|findstr /r "REG$"') do (
      set name=%%e & set name=!name:~0,-4!)
    for %%f in (MULTI EXPAND SZ) do (set data=!data:%%f=!)
    for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=_" %%g in ("!data!") do (
      if %%h NEQ "" (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('echo %%g^|findstr /r "REG$"') do (
          set name2=%%i & set name2=!name2:~0,-4!
          set name=!name! !name2! 
          call :trim tname !name!
          set name=!tname: =_!
          set data=%%h
        )
      )
    )
)
endlocal & set "%~3=%name%" & set "%~4=%data%"
exit /b

:Trim <return> <string>
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ("%*") do set "%%a=%%b"
exit /b
```

Comment: Does it not fail for values with spaces in its name?

Comment: @MC ND I didn't have any paths with spaces in my registry when I tested it. I think quoting the path in the reg add line should take care of that though. I edited my answer to include that. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, i have not explained it clear enough, my fault. I'm talking about the "value name" and not the data inside the value. What you are retrieving into `%%b`. The value names can have spaces. In my case, just an example, under `HKCU\Identities`. Maybe it is not applicable to this question, i have not checked all the involved keys.

Comment: @MC ND I see what you're saying now. I had to create a dummy key and Name value for testing. It does indeed fail if the Name value has spaces in it. I'm not sure how to fix it yet either since there is no way to determine how many tokens to use in that case. I'll think of something. ;)

Comment: thx for helping! - but but the space problem just hit me:
`reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Us
er Shell Folders" /v My /d "REG_EXPAND_SZ\\systemb\h\foo\bar\Music"
/f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Us
er Shell Folders" /v My /d "REG_EXPAND_SZ\\systemb\h\foo\bar\Picture
s" /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Us
er Shell Folders" /v Personal /d "\\systemb\h\foo\bar\Documents" /f`

Comment: It looks like you're experiencing what MC ND and I are discussing. I'll have a fix for it in a few minutes if he doesn't come up with one before me.

Comment: This was a lot harder than I expected but it seems to work. ;)

Comment: Really nice, i didn't think in the underscore. But, sorry Matt, has problems. Value names can include underscores, and you can have a problem with `name=!name:REG=!` if `REG` is part of the value name.

Comment: @MC ND Thanks. True but I searched my registry for any valuenames that had underscores in them and didn't find any with an UNC path for the data so I figured it was a reasonable compromise. I've fixed the case where valuename can have REG in it.

Comment: @MattWilliamson, sorry, regresion to start point: spaces inside !name!. If you are splitting in the underscore, and know the text ends with REG, why not remove the ending characters with a substring assignment?

Comment: @MC ND I guess great minds think alike ;) I was already going that route. I decided to start fresh and found a few more bugs that needed to be fixed after I started adding more and more types of valuenames into my dummy reg key. Still not handling underscores in valuenames though.

Comment: @MC ND I think I got it. finally.